# Apache .htaccess mod_rewrite - can't redirect to a file with the same prefix?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Why this .htaccess rule doesn't work? I get 404 when requesting `mydomain.com/login`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
```

If I change `^login$` to `^logn$` or `login.php` to `login1.php` it does work.

I can change my file names, but I wonder why it doesn't work.

The problem is happening on Ubuntu 14.04. Apache version: 2.4.2.
On my development Windows7 it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is correct, but you probably have a problem with multiviews. Try it like this (only adding the top line, and giving you an optional slash after `login` so that `login/` also gets redirected):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]
```